# Finding a document in Mongoose based on id array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, Trade and Work, that act as categories and subcategories of labor. I want new additions to automatically pick a Trade based on the Work given, but I can't seem to get something that finds a Trade containing the Work id:

labor.server.model.js:

```
const WorkSchema = new Schema({
    WORK_NAME: String
}, {
    autoIndex: false
});

const TradeSchema = new Schema({
    TRADE_NAME: String,
    WORKS: [WorkSchema]
}, {
    autoIndex: false
});
```

api.server.controller.js:

```
exports.addlabor = function(req, res, next) {
    var Labor = mongoose.model('Labor');
    var Trade = mongoose.model('Trade');
    if (!req.body.CATEGORY) {
        Trade
            .find({WORKS: [req.body.SUBCATEGORY]}) // SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
            .exec(function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    req.body.CATEGORY = data._id;
                }
            });
    }

    const labor = new Labor(req.body);
    labor.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.redirect('/labor');
    });
};
```

Comment: So what you want to do is to find works that are referenced in trade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
var work = 'painting' //req.body.SUBCATEGORY string

//change to find to get all matching
Trade.findOne( { 'WORKS.WORK_NAME' : work }, function( err,doc ){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(doc);
})
```

console out

```
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$ node so4.js
`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Mongoose: trades.findOne({ 'WORKS.WORK_NAME': 'painting' }, { fields: {} })
{ _id: 5a5d6b50d1c8c30ade0c3d4c,
  TRADE_NAME: 'painter',
  __v: 0,
  WORKS: [ { WORK_NAME: 'painting', _id: 5a5d6b50d1c8c30ade0c3d4d } ] }
^C
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$
```

Comment: Brilliant, `'WORKS._id'` was exactly what I needed, thanks!